# Why Func<T> is used in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, delegates

One of my colleague came across [this](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/SingleServiceResolver.cs) code and we are unable to understand why `_resolverThunk` is needed.

Summary of the code looks like this:

```
private Func<IDependencyResolver> _resolverThunk;

public SingleServiceResolver()
{
    _resolverThunk = () => DependencyResolver.Current;
}

private TService GetValueFromResolver()
{
   TService result = _resolverThunk().GetService<TService>();
   return result;
}
```

Comment: later in the code you can see that `_resolverThunk` could be set to other values

Comment: That sort of pattern is a type factory approach, for resolving stuff when you need it as opposed to having everything resolved upfront. However, it is usually a very targeted resolver. This seems very generic and I don't see any benefit to having the `Func<IDependencyResolver>` instead of just holding an `IDependencyResolver` reference.

Comment: This is so the code that passed in the `Func<>` can change the implementation of getting `IDependencyResolver` instances at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at another internal constructor, it sets the `_resolverThunk` from parameter. So it makes sense.

```
 internal SingleServiceResolver(Func<TService> staticAccessor, TService defaultValue, IDependencyResolver resolver, string callerMethodName)
        : this(staticAccessor, defaultValue, callerMethodName)
 {
     if (resolver != null)
     {
            _resolverThunk = () => resolver;
     }
 }
```

Otherwise, there is no reason to do it.

Comment: I think I did not get your point because I still think it could be just `IDependencyResolver` instead of `Func<IDependencyResolver>` (:

Comment: @MehmetAtaş Nope. `DependencyResolver.Current` is a property, so it could be changed anytime (even in getter),  if you use a `Func` here, it will get the latest value as opposed to the field (which will get you the old snapshot). Even if it is not a property, it could be changed anytime, they wanted to get the latest value all the time, so they choose to use `Func`.